# How to test the equivalence of clinical parameters between two contingency tables (confusion matrix)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, epidemiology, contingency-tables

What will be the easiest way to compare the derivations (clinical parameters) from two contingency tables? I want to test two 2x2 tables with their respective True Positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative entries ($H_0$: Table 1 = Table 2 *vs.* $H_1$: Table 1 ≠ Table 2). I want to compare statistically the sensitivities, specificities, negative and positive predictive values of the two tables. Sample size for the two tables is different.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it means to you to "test" a pair of tables?  What are you trying to find out?  What does it mean to you for two tables to be "equal"?  As part of that, it would be really helpful to explain how the data arose, because that will provide information essential to determine a probability model for the tables.

Comment: If you mean equivalent in the sense that the cell probabilities are equal, then this is a classical $\chi^2$ test situation

Comment: Sorry for the unclear request. I am trying to estimate if the sensitivity, specificity, negative predictive value and positive predictive value from both tables are statistically equivalent. Sensitivity = true positive/(true positive+false negative); Specificity = true negative/(true negative+false positive); Negative Predictive Value = true negative/(true negative+false negative); Positive Predictive Value = (true positive/(true positive+false positive).

Comment: Do you want to compare those four characteristics simultaneously or one at a time?

Comment: Simultaneously if possible. It could one at a time but the test will have too take care of the dependence of the variables I guess!

Comment: ROC curves are often used to compare the performance of two diagnostic tests.  I am not particularly knowledgeable of them, but the `roc.test` section of the pROC package [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf) has some information. Also consider investigating the other ROC-related packages on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/), if you are an R user.

Comment: Do you only have the contingency table, or do you also have the original data which the contingencytable summarizes?

Comment: I have the  original data for both contingency tables that I wanted to compared.

Comment: I already tested the AUC of both data set if the difference is significant or not. But AUC is a bi-dimensional variable (sensitivity and specificity). I guess if I can do it with 4 dimensions (adding positive and negative predictive values) the result can answer my initial question precisely!